# UI for a Desktop App

Tags: java, user-interface, desktop

I have a desktop application . The functionality is complete, but user interface requires a lot of work. I am looking for UI tools.My current operating system is Windows and application is required to run on both Windows and Linux.

Can you guys recommend any?

The software is customized file management application for a specific client, with future plans of web integration.

Thanks in advance :)

Application Environment
Lang : java,
IDE : Eclipse 3.4,
Target Platforms : Windows Vista-OpenSuse 11

Comment: sorry for the typo, updated it now
thanks David for replying quickly, the software currently uses swing components, honestly it kindof looks crude :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SWT is another option. The advantages are a look-and-feel closer to the native platform, and generally faster execution times. The main disadvantage is that you will have to have different distributions for different target platforms, as SWT depends on platform specific libraries.

With an eye toward the web integration, look at GWT. You write your interface in Java but it gets generated into Javascript and can thus be run in a browser. This may make your deployments easier. On the downside, you lose a bit of the rich client UI, but maybe you don't even need that. It all depends on how complex your UI is.

A word of advice: you mentioned future plans of web integration. Take special care to isolate what logic you can from the UI. Keep the UI as clean as possible, and then you may be able to use the same logic in the web UI either on the client or the server.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking for a GUI designer you could check out [Netbeans IDE](http://netbeans.org) which has a built-in Swing user-interface builder.

Alternatively you could build a front-end in [JavaFX](http://javafx.com). There's not much tooling for FX yet but a new tool was recently previewed at JavaOne 09. Not sure when it's being released.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Qt a few times and find it very good at this sort of thing - 
[Qt Home Page](http://www.qtsoftware.com/products/) I'm not sure if it's exactly what you're looking for as your application is complete, however, but it may be worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

Found an excellent fix,

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(myform);
```

looks so cool in my vista and suse , its enough for now.

Thanks for everybody for helping out